# Open a new window in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-jdt

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin which add a new editor based on a table viewer. When I double click on a cell of that table, I want to display a new window allowing to modify the content of a cell (i got many fields and features to implement in this window so i don't want to use a simple input dialog box).

Directly opening a JFrame seems to be a bad practice so what is the best way to create that windows ?

Comment: You really should be using SWT in an Eclipse plugin. Swing controls will look different from the rest of Eclipse and you won't be able to use a lot of support code provided by Eclipse (such as its table cell editing support).

Comment: You want to open a new window to edit the contents of that cell, or of multiple cells? It's unclear. Usually when you edit a table's contents, it is one cell at a time. Anything more complicated, and it sounds like either the wrong control or the wrong approach.